# Duplicate cells on each load of tableView from coredata

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, duplicates

The view shows duplicate rows for each record in CoreData which keep multiplying on each reload. The code is as under.
What happen is whenever I add record then I view record it shows me the record. Then I click back for the homepage after that when I click on view record I see the copy of same record. So now I have 2 same records. Can anyone please help me with and I think the problem is in table view so here is my table view controller code

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
var Rec = [Records]()
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var firstLoad = true
    func nondel() -> [Records]
    {
        var nodellist = [Records]()
        for note in Rec
        {
            if(note.del == nil)
            {
                nodellist.append(note)
            }
        }
        return nodellist

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if(firstLoad)
        {
        firstLoad = false
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

            let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Records")
            do{
                let results: NSArray = try context.fetch(request) as NSArray
                for result in results {
                    let note = result as! Records
                    Rec.append(note)
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Fetch Failed")
            }
        }

    
    }

    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell") as! TableViewCell
        
        let thisrec: Records!
        thisrec = nondel()[indexPath.row]
        cell.idLB.text = thisrec.id
        cell.nameLB.text = thisrec.name
        cell.lastLB.text = thisrec.last
        cell.genderLB.text = thisrec.gender
        cell.ageLB.text = thisrec.age
        cell.addressLB.text = thisrec.address
        return cell


}
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return nondel().count
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editNote", sender: self)
        }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "editNote")
        {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            let recDetail = segue.destination as? AddViewController
            let selectedCell: Records!
            selectedCell = nondel()[indexPath.row]
            recDetail!.selectedCell = selectedCell
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first ten lines or so tell it all.

Comment: @Deepankar Rawal did you ever figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unbelievable cumbersome.

- First of all never declare a data source outside of any class.
- Second of all never use a function to build an array as table view data source.
- Third of all `firstRun` is pointless because `viewDidLoad` is called only once anyway.
- Fourth of all rather than filtering the received records *manually* apply a predicate to the fetch request

Further it's highly recommended to name Core Data entities always in singular form (`Record`) and to use the specific generic fetch request of this entity.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var records = [Record]()
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let request : NSFetchRequest<Record> = Record.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "del != nil")
        do {
             records = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch { print("Fetch Failed", error) }
    }        
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell") as! TableViewCell
        
        let thisrec = records[indexPath.row]
        cell.idLB.text = thisrec.id
        cell.nameLB.text = thisrec.name
        cell.lastLB.text = thisrec.last
        cell.genderLB.text = thisrec.gender
        cell.ageLB.text = thisrec.age
        cell.addressLB.text = thisrec.address
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return records.count
    }

 ...
```